# give the colour to navigation title

Tags: ios

i need to display the textcolour white in navigation title.
I tried with some code .But the colour in not changing.Now My code as below.

in Appdelegate:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //to set the background status bar......
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.215, green: 0.086, blue: 0.298, alpha:1.0)

    }//to set the light color
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
         //declare the tab controller

    let tabBarController = QM_TabBarController()

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)
    navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false;

    //setting the navigation color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.27, green: 0.14, blue: 0.36, alpha:1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white // Do only if you want


    //make the tab bar controller as root
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

          return true
    }

func uicolorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32)->UIColor{
    let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
    let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
    let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0
    return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1.0)
}
```

In TabBarController as below.

```
    let controllers = [viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,viewController5]
         self.viewControllers = controllers.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
           self.viewControllers = controllers


    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.27, green: 0.125, blue: 0.36, alpha:1.0)

     viewController1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "HOME", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "HOME"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "HOME1"))

 viewController1.navigationItem.title = "HOME"
```

Here black colour is displaying but i need white colour title.

Answer (score 2):

Please write below code in your appDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 15.0)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white // Do only if you want

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the navigation title color then try this,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
self.navigationItem.title = "FIRST"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```