# Identify which button was pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How to identify which button was pressed. I have 3 button actions. Now I have another button which when pressed it will identify which button from the 3 was pressed. Because first you have to click from the 3 buttons. After clicking from the 3 buttons then you will click
idenfifywhichpressed button and this button will identify or print which button from the 3 was pressed.

```
//this button will identify
@IBAction func idenfifywhichpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

The 3 buttons

```
@IBAction func btn1(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBAction func btn2(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBAction func btn3(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Comment: You can set tag of each button and take one public variable, assign that tag in public variable and from that public variable you can identify it

Comment: During setup, mark the button tag as 1,2,3... When your click action done, check the `sender.tag`...

Comment: Instead of writing `button` different actions, create only 1 action and set `tag` to your `button` so it's easy to identify by `tag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
var index:Int = 0
```

Now do this, FYI, set button tags accordingly 1,2 and 3...

```
@IBAction func btn1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    index = sender.tag
}

@IBAction func btn2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    index = sender.tag
}

@IBAction func btn3(_ sender: UIButton) {
    index = sender.tag
}
```

now this,

```
@IBAction func idenfifywhichpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if index == 1 {
        //Button 1 Pressed
    }else if index == 2 {
        //Button 2 Pressed
    } else if index == 3{
        //Button 3 Pressed
    }
}
```

FYI. You can use `Switch` statement as well in `idenfifywhichpressed` method.

Update. Do not create three methods for btn1, btn2 and btn3, just create one method and assign tag accordingly for simplicity.

Comment: Sir , how about for example if index == 1 {
      i want to trigger action button 1
    }

Comment: You can call btn1 selector in that case

Comment: Sir also i have a question i have create a navigation bar from the object library how can i change its height , color and font style?

Comment: you can find my answer here for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793174/give-the-colour-to-navigation-title/49793286#49793286

Comment: yeah can you please answer my question in comment thanks

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck, Suppose you have 100 `buttons` than do you create 100 `action` for them?

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck, it's good way and less coding to create 1 `action` for 100 `button` and fetch which `button` is tapped by using `tag`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

**Declare an enum**

```
  enum SelectedButtonTag: Int {
     case First
     case Second
     case Third
  }
```

**Button Action**

Connect the three button actions to this method with different tag

```
   @IBAction func idenfifywhichpressed(sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case SelectedButtonTag.First.rawValue:
            print("do something when first button is tapped")
        case SelectedButtonTag.Second.rawValue:
            print("do something when second button is tapped")
        case SelectedButtonTag.Third.rawValue:
            print("do something when third button is tapped")
        default:
            print("default")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kudos on the enum. I've posted a somewhat cleaned-up version of the same idea below.

Comment: While this is fine for handling several buttons with one action, this doesn't actually address the question that was asked. The question is asking how check which of 3 buttons was tapped when the user taps a 4th button.

Answer (score 1):

Small improvement on @prajnaranjan-das answer: casting to an enum immediately to clean up some cruft and remove the need to implement default in the switch...

```
enum ButtonTag: Int {
    case First
    case Second
    case Third
 }

func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let knownSender = ButtonTag(rawValue: sender.tag) else { return }
    switch knownSender {
    case .First:
        print("do something when first button is tapped")
    case .Second:
        print("do something when second button is tapped")
    case .Third:
        print("do something when third button is tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is fine for handling several buttons with one action, this doesn't actually address the question that was asked. The question is asking how check which of 3 buttons was tapped when the user taps a 4th button.

Answer (score 1):

This is helped for me (swift 5.0)

```
@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.currentTitle) // <----------
    }
    

}
```

Comment: While this is fine for handling several buttons with one action, this doesn't actually address the question that was asked. The question is asking how check which of 3 buttons was tapped when the user taps a 4th button.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach.

```
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    switch(sender) {
    case zeroPctButton:
        print("0%")
        break;
    case tenPctButton:
        print("10%")
        break;
    case twentyPctButton:
        print("20%")
        break;
    default:
        print(" - you fail - ")
        break;
    }
```

Comment: While this is fine for handling several buttons with one action, this doesn't actually address the question that was asked. The question is asking how check which of 3 buttons was tapped when the user taps a 4th button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a variable like

```
var checkBtn: String?
```

inside 1st button change the variable value

```
checkBtn = "1"
```

inside 2nd button change the variable value

```
checkBtn = "2"
```

inside 3rd button change the variable value

```
checkBtn = "3"

@IBAction func idenfifywhichpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // just print the value of CheckBtn

    print(checkBtn)

    //this will give you which btn pressed right

}
```